# Curl HTML content behind website with login (manuscript status tracking)

Tags: html, curl, cookies, authentication

I would like to track the manuscript status for a paper submitted to Nature Materials.

This is the landing page: http://mts-nm.nature.com/cgi-bin/main.plex

I am the first author so I have the login and password.

When I login, I am redirected to the tracking status page:

http://mts-nm.nature.com/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=status_details&j_id=8&ms_id=32234&ms_rev_no=0&ms_id_key=SFfgnknwkgnregKsdnflsfgqn

I want to parse the following table:

```
</TABLE>
<BR>&nbsp;<BR>
         <TABLE BORDER=5>
         <TR>
            <TH>Stage</TH>
            <TH>Start Date</TH>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Manuscript received</TD><TD>16th May 18</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Manuscript submitted</TD><TD>15th May 18</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

This is how I attempt to extract the relevant parts of the table using curl:

```
curl --user username:password --cookie-jar ./my_cookie 'http://mts-nm.nature.com/cgi-bin/main.plex'
curl --cookie mycookie 'http://mts-nm.nature.com/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=status_details&j_id=8&ms_id=32234&ms_rev_no=0&ms_id_key=SFfgnknwkgnregKsdnflsfgqn' > parsed.html
grep 'May 18' parsed.html
```

Since it does not curl the page with the status information, this returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: To troubleshoot, try the second command  with `--verbose` or even `--trace-ascii trace.txt` and removing the redirection at the end. There's planty of info about cURL automated login so you should be able to fix it.